# jsonp data to rder html tag as html

Tags: html, jsrender

hello I have json object as follows ..

```
[Object { Address="Space Hall <br/> GSBS Ground",  EventStartDate="4/12/2013 12:00:00 AM",  EventEndDate="4/12/2013 12:00:00 AM",  more...}, 
Object { Address="Space Hall <br/> GSBS Ground",  EventStartDate="4/13/2013 12:00:00 AM",  EventEndDate="4/13/2013 12:00:00 AM",  more...}]
```

I am rendering this using jsrender in template as

```
<script id="jsTemplate" type="text/html">  
   <tr>
   <td>{{=Address}}
   </td>
   </tr>
</script>
```

now the issue is 'Address' contains break i.e. 'br' tag inside it... so what can I do to consider this as html tag only and not display string like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
{{:Address}}
```

if you want display html markup.

You can find more details on [jsrender demo page](http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/03_converters-and-encoding.html)

Comment: {{:Address}} does not work.. even I saw this as solution but it didn't work for me

Comment: I think you are using old version of jsrender. the {{= syntax is not valid anymore. Here is example on jsfiddle that shows how to use with {{: http://jsfiddle.net/UaVph/

Answer (score 0):

Oh it got solved...  I found from other source... changed to {{=Address!}} and it works